# Flutter: Why does change in package (flutter-tools) has no impact (in flutter doctor)?

Tags: dart, flutter

`flutter doctor` has issues -

```js
 Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
    Sending crash report to Google.
    Crash report sent (report ID: a5fb11a50ca9bb90)
    Unhandled exception:
    NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isMacOS' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: isMacOS
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
    #1      IOSDevices.supportsPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/devices.dart:34)
    #2      DeviceManager._platformDiscoverers.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:85)
    #3      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:439)
```

It seems to be a bug with flutter. (I don't exactly know what I did, so unable to help reproduce it, but I'm stuck with this issue. Re-installing flutter didn't help too.)

I'm trying to hard-code the platform check in `ios/devices.dart`, since I'm on windows & developing for android.

But my changes -
`

```
@override
  bool get supportsPlatform {
    return false;
```

`
have no impact.

`flutter doctor` still throws the same error, at the same line number.

Could it be some caching issue? Or a `build` issue? (so far it seems that the [packages need not be built](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1490) but maybe they do?)

Comment: It might contains snapshots in the downloads that it executes instead of the source files directly.

Comment: Okay, I will check. Where should I look (directory/folder)?

Comment: Check for files with `.dart.snapshot` or similar (don't remember exactly). You shouldn't need to do that though.

Comment: Please file a bug for us (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) if flutter tools has issues on some platform :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : found it `flutter\bin\cache\flutter_tools.snapshot`, thanks!

@xster : I'm not sure how ended up here, will file a bug if/when I do. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of recompiling the flutter tools executable on each `flutter` command invocation, the [snapshot](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Snapshots) is saved in a cache which rebuilds when you upgrade flutter (or really just with each git commits to the repo behind the scene).

To manually trigger a rebuild, you can delete your $FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/flutter_tools.* and the flutter tools will rebuild the next time you invoke `flutter`